# How to override the value of __TIME__ and __DATE__ macros using command line options?

Tags: c, macros, clang, c-preprocessor, armclang

In a project where the `__FILE__` and `__DATE__` macros are used in one of the modules, I am trying to redefine the values of these macros to explicit values during build time. Trying to use the `-D` option, like `-D__TIME__=01:23:45` gave me a compilation error.

```
Compiling ./Console.c
In file included from <built-in>:324:
<command line>:41:9: error: redefining builtin macro [-Werror,-Wbuiltin-macro-redefined]
#define __TIME__ 01:23:45
        ^
1 error generated.
```

Is there a way to set these macros (and similar predefined macros) from the command line, w/o altering the source code itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Compile with the switch `-Wno-builtin-macro-redefined`.

That will disable the warning (including the error you get because you are also compiling with `-Werror`). I cannot assure you what it will do with the macro definition—Clang appears to be obeying the request to use the command-line definition, but I do not know it will do so in all circumstances.

Comment: GCC-5.4.0 also appears to obey the request as well. (Of course, one needs to use `'-D__TIME__="foo"' '-D__DATE__="bar"'`, as the macros should expand to a string literal.)